How do I type generic callables with default value in Python?
I have the following function:
T = TypeVar("T")


def handle_func(x: int, func: Callable[[int], T]) -> T:
    return func(x)

and I can use it like so:
handle_func(1, lambda x: x + 1)
handle_func(1, lambda x: x == 1)

When I run mypy, all is good.
But how can I add a default value to func?
When I do this:
def handle_func(x: int, func: Callable[[int], T] = lambda x: x + 1) -> T:
    return func(x)

and run mypy I get:
error: Incompatible default for argument "func" (default has type "Callable[[int], int]", argument has type "Callable[[int], T]")  [assignment]
error: Incompatible return value type (got "int", expected "T")  [return-value]

How can I type this? What am I understanding incorrectly?

Does this answer your question? Annotating function with TypeVar and default value results in union type

One way to handle this is to separate the two forms:

Pass a single argument, always get an int (not generic); and
Pass two arguments, get whatever the second returns (generic in T).

You can do this as overloads:
from typing import Callable, overload, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

@overload
def handle_func(x: int) -> int:
    ...

@overload
def handle_func(x: int, func: Callable[[int], T]) -> T:
    ...

def handle_func(x, func = lambda x: x + 1):
    return func(x)

mypy Playground

can you please explain why the first overload definition would be without the second argument?

@Meir because, as explained just before the snippet, that's the form where you pass a single argument x (and therefore use the default value of func).

This is the solution recommended on the GitHub issue: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3737#issuecomment-316263133.

The type checker just complains that the non overloaded handle_func is not typed. How can I type it as well?

I solved this by typing the non-overloaded with a more generic type (Callable and return Any)

One approach is to simply cast the default value:
def handle_func(
    x: int,
    func: Callable[[int], T] = cast(Callable[[int], T], lambda x: x + 1)
) -> T:
    return func(x)

Demo with mypy: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=b840e26f46173e646cab2fd08e266c79

In general I try to shy away from using cast as this just forces the type checking to "trust" me and potentially introduces mistakes

Yes, but the unfortunate fact is that you can't annotate a lambda function with the current typing system, and @jonrsharpe's solution does not help type checking the default callable value either (for example, it does not complain if you make lambda x, y: x + 1 a default value), so you might as well cast the value to make mypy happy.

I think that I had two issues here - the first was the default to the generic, and for that I accepted the first answer, and the problem with typing lambda functions which your cast solves
